# How to manage react-native-push-notification and login redirect in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-native-push-notification

Let me explain my problem here.

***Current app state***

- The initial page of my app is the login screen. That's the page user go by default when they open the app. I then check if they're already logged in. If so I send them to the homepage.

***What I'm trying to do***

- When the user opens a notification, it sends him to a specific page
  depending on the action.
- When the user opens the app, the app redirects him to a specific page
  if he's already logged in.

*The above actions are both executed when the user opens the app from a notification which is a problem.*

***My problem***

- When the user clicks on the notification, he gets redirected to the specified page but then gets redirected back to the homepage because both actions get executed.

I'm not sure how to deal with this issue. Is there a better to do what I'm trying to do?

**Login.js**

```
class Login extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    let currentUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    if (currentUser) {
      Actions.searchUsers()
    }
  }
  ...
```

**App.js**

```
PushNotification.configure({
    onNotification: function(notification) {
        if (notification.data.userID) {
          Actions.userShow({id: notification.data.userId});
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: @NicNilov just did.

Comment: @Hugo did you get anywhere with this?